# How to swipe the keyboard along InteractivePopGestureRecognizer?

Tags: xcode, ios7, keyboard, uigesturerecognizer, pan

I was wondering how to swipe the ViewController with a visible keyboard?

in iOS 7 I can swipe the ViewController from side to side, but the keyboard stays put.

in short, I would like to get to the following state:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### *Update:*

I can't recommend the original solution. While it performed well (when it performed at all), it was an unreliable hack, and could easily break the pop gesture recognizer.

My colleague [Dave Lyon](https://github.com/davelyon) came up with a great solution using iOS 7 view controller transitions and packaged it up into a pod:

https://github.com/cotap/TAPKeyboardPop

Once installed, just import the main file and you should be good to go.

---

#### *Original:*

I'd love to know if there's a better way of doing this, but I was able to achieve the behavior by adding the keyboard's view as a subview of the view controller's main view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textView.inputAccessoryView = [UIView new];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                   name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                 object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (self.textView.isFirstResponder) {
        UIView *keyboardView = self.textView.inputAccessoryView.superview;
        if (keyboardView) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.view addSubview:keyboardView];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I've found you can also animate the keyboard with the gesture (via `addTarget:action:`), but the performance is abysmal and doesn't cleanly animate if the gesture is prematurely canceled.

Comment: hi, stephen. Unfortunately - this isn't a good solution for me. the popGesture breaks right after I use this approach.

Comment: @TomerRubin I realized that you must have an inputAccessoryView set on the UITextView (or UITextField) for this to work. I've tested the (updated) above code in a blank project and it worked just fine.